# TypeScript type 'object' vs Object interface, and why no 'array' type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could someone please explain in clear sense why there is a type `object` in TypeScript, and why would you use it instead of JavaScript `Object` interface?

Similarly, why is there no `array` type but rather JavaScript interface `Array` is used?

It is somewhat confusing to see similar examples over the Internet where `Array<Object>` and `Array<object>` are in similar context.

Comment: it is fully and expertly explained here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`object` represents anything that's not a primitive; so anything that's not `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `null`, or `undefined`.

`Object` represents functionality that's common to all objects; so things like .toString() and .valueOf(). But be warned! Because of boxing (boxing is where a primitive gets wrapped in an object), primitives effectively have these properties as well, so the following are perfectly legal:

```
const a: Object = 5;
const b: Object = "hello";
const c: Object = true;
```

In contrast, the following would all be errors:

```
const a: object = 5;
const b: object = "hello";
const c: object = true;
```

For that reason, `Object` is almost never what you want to use, and you should use `object` instead.

See also the Typescript page on [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Nicholas Tower! And why is there no `array` type...?

Comment: What do you imagine `array` would be that's different from `Array`? arrays aren't primitives, so it can't be an indication of primitiveness like we have for `number`, `boolean`, etc. `object` exists to fulfill a special role of distinghishing primitives from nonprimitives, but i can't think of an analogous role that `array` could fulfill.

Comment: It's just confusing to mix up Array as a JavaScript interface with these TypeScript types.